# Change date format after transforming elements

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I have an initial XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pi:Payroll_Extract_Employees xmlns:pi="urn:com.workday/picof">
<pi:Header>
    <pi:Updated_From>2017-09-07T02:23:04.000-07:00</pi:Updated_From>
</pi:Header>
<pi:Employee>
    <pi:Summary>
        <pi:Employee_ID>00000001</pi:Employee_ID>
    </pi:Summary>
    <pi:Time_Off>
            <pi:Code_Name>WTR</pi:Code_Name>
            <pi:Time_Off_Type>1260</pi:Time_Off_Type>
            <pi:Time_Off_Date>2017-09-07</pi:Time_Off_Date>
            <pi:Quantity>8</pi:Quantity>
            <pi:Unit_of_Time>HOURS</pi:Unit_of_Time>
    </pi:Time_Off>
    <pi:Additional_Information>
        <pi:Strike_1>11-sept.-2017,2 Hours=9570</pi:Strike_1>
    </pi:Additional_Information>
</pi:Employee>
<pi:Employee>
    <pi:Summary>
        <pi:Employee_ID>00000002</pi:Employee_ID>
    </pi:Summary>
    <pi:Additional_Information>
        <pi:Strike_1>22-sept.-2017,8 Hours=9570</pi:Strike_1>
        <pi:Unjustified_Absence_1>25-sept.-2017,8 Hours=9700</pi:Unjustified_Absence_1>
    </pi:Additional_Information>
</pi:Employee>
```

And XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
xmlns:pi="urn:com.workday/picof"
version="2.0">

<xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <pi:Payroll_Extract_Employees>
        <xsl:copy-of select="//pi:Header"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="//pi:Employee">
        <pi:Employee>
            <xsl:copy-of select="pi:Summary"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="pi:Time_Off"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="pi:Additional_Information/*"/>
        </pi:Employee>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </pi:Payroll_Extract_Employees>     
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="pi:Additional_Information/*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::pi:Payroll_Extract_Employees">
        <xsl:with-param name="UnpaidTO" select="current()"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="pi:Payroll_Extract_Employees">
    <xsl:param name="UnpaidTO"/>
        <pi:Time_Off>
            <pi:Code_Name>Unpaid Time Off</pi:Code_Name>
            <pi:Time_Off_Type><xsl:value-of select="substring-after($UnpaidTO,'=')"/></pi:Time_Off_Type>
            <pi:Time_Off_Date><xsl:value-of select="substring-before($UnpaidTO,',')"/></pi:Time_Off_Date>
            <pi:Quantity><xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($UnpaidTO,','),' ')"/></pi:Quantity>
            <pi:Unit_of_Time><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-before($UnpaidTO,'='),' ')"/></pi:Unit_of_Time>
        </pi:Time_Off>   
 </xsl:template>

 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Code is going well so far. But on the final output, I would like to change the date format of **pi:Time_Off_Date** which is not in the format of yyyy-MM-dd. As seen in the initial XML, it is in the format of dd-MMM-yyyy. Date is in French language so MMM could either be:

janv.
févr.
mars
avril
mai
juin
juil.
août
sept.
oct.
nov.
déc.

so it should be
01
02
03
04
05
06
07
08
09
10
11
12
respectively.

so the final output of all **pi:Time_Off_Date** will be yyyy-MM-dd.

I tried adding the code below. But nothing seems to happen. Is there any way I could make it? Really need help on this. Thanks!

```
<xsl:template match="pi:Time_Off_Date">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:call-template name="TODate">
    <xsl:with-param name="dd-mmm-yyyy" select="."/>
  </xsl:call-template>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="TODate">
  <xsl:param name="dd-mmm-yyyy"/>
   <xsl:variable name="dd" select="substring-before($dd-mmm-yyyy, '-')"/>
   <xsl:variable name="mmm-yyyy" select="substring-after($dd-mmm-yyyy, '-')"/>
   <xsl:variable name="mmm" select="substring-before($mmm-yyyy, '-')"/>
   <xsl:variable name="yyyy" select="substring-after($mmm-yyyy, '-')"/>
<xsl:value-of select="$yyyy"/>
 <xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="$mmm = 'janv.'">01</xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="$mmm = 'févr.'">02</xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="$mmm = 'mars'">03</xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="$mmm = 'avril'">04</xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="$mmm = 'mai'">05</xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="$mmm = 'juin'">06</xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="$mmm = 'juil.'">07</xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="$mmm = 'août'">08</xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="$mmm = 'sept.'">09</xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="$mmm = 'oct'">10</xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="$mmm = 'nov.'">11</xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="$mmm = 'déc.'">12</xsl:when>
  </xsl:choose>
<xsl:value-of select="$dd"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

The immediate reason that your template for pi:Time_Off_Date is not making any difference in the output is that there is no call to xsl:apply-templates in your stylesheet which would cause that template to be evaluated.

Your stylesheet will start execution by evaluating the template that matches /, which generates a pi:Payroll_Extract_Employees element, copies all pi:Header elements into it, and generates a pi:Employee element for each pi:Employee in the input.  Within the output pi:Employee element, you'll get unchanged copies of any pi:Summary and pi:Time_Off elements which appear as children of the corresponding input pi:Employee element, and any children of any pi:Additional_Information child of the input pi:Employee element will be processed by the matching template.  This, in turn, calls xsl:apply-templates on the ancestor pi:Payroll_Extract_Employees element.

If you insert

```
<xsl:message>Hi!</xsl:message>
```

into your template for pi:Time_Off_Date, you can easily confirm for yourself that it's not being called:  you will not see any Hi! messages when you evaluate the stylesheet.

You may find it helpful to read up on the difference between 'push' and 'pull' style processing in XSLT and to experiment with moving toward a more push-oriented style; right now your stylesheet is mostly pull style, which means that adding templates to produce new behavior will typically have no effect.

You should also note, however, (especially if you shift to a push-style transformation) that the first instance of pi:Time_Off_Date *is* in yyyy-mm-dd format and needs no change.  I think you might do well to check, in your code for transforming the date format, that the input is in the format your template is expecting.

(Some users of XSLT 2.0 would probably also prefer to do this with a function, not a named template, but I think you're fine with a named template.)